# Mapnik.NET Layer Datasource paths

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mapnik

I have been trying to create a Layer using Mapnik.NET (https://sourceforge.net/p/mapniknet/) but am unable to set paths.
Mapnik.NET is a .NET wrapper around a C++ dll.

I have attempted to set the 'file' parameter for a shape file in XML and code but always get the error:

'Could not create datasource. No plugin found for type 'shape' (searched in: )'.

I have tried lots of differnt paths but have had no success. e.g.:

"shoreline_300.shp" (with file in base of C: and in debug folder)

"/shoreline_300.shp"

"shoreline_300.shp"

"C:shoreline_300.shp"

"C:\shoreline_300.shp"

"file:///shoreline_300.shp"

Has anyone been able to successfully set paths?

XML:

```
<Datasource>
      <Parameter name="type">shape</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="file">/shoreline_300.shp</Parameter>
</Datasource>
```

C#:

```
ValuesDictionary vd = new ValuesDictionary();
vd.Add("type", "shape");
vd.Add("file", "/shoreline_300.shp");

IDatasource ds = DatasourceCache.Create(vd);
worldLayer.Datasource = ds;
self.Map.Layers.Add(worldLayer);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've only just started exploring the use of `MapnikCs` hence the time lapse in responding but I've found that if you call

```
DatasourceCache.RegisterDatasources(path\to\datasource\plugins)
```

before creating the `datasource` you might find that your code works.